# Basis of quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Given the follwing vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

$v:= \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\,$, $a:=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}\,$, $b:=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\,$,  $c:= \begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$

(i) Determine a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4/\langle v\rangle$

(ii) Is the subset $\{[a],[b],[c]\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4/\langle v\rangle$ linearly independent?

To (i)
Since $\{(1,1,1,1)^T, (1,0,0,0)^T, (0,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,0)^T\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, the added coset classes are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4/\langle v\rangle$:
$$\{(1,0,0,0)^T+\langle v\rangle, (0,1,0,0)^T+\langle v\rangle, (0,0,1,0)^T +\langle v\rangle\}$$

Is this correct? How can I check for linear independence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $\mathbb{R}^4/\langle v\rangle$ has dimension $3$, don't you?

So, since $\{v,e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is clearly a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, the cosets
$[e_1]$, $[e_2]$ and $[e_3]$ form a spanning set of the quotient space. Hence they are linearly independent.

For the second part, suppose
$$
\alpha[a]+\beta[b]+\gamma[c]=[0].
$$
This means
$$
\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma c=\delta v
$$
for some $\delta$. Can you go on?

Comment: So i have just to solve a system of linear equations? $\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma c -\delta v$ = 0?

Comment: @fear.xD Yes. If you get non zero solutions for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, then the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: The subset is linearly independent, because $\alpha , \beta ,\gamma , \delta = 0$

Comment: @fear.xD Pari-GP confirms that the vectors are linearly independent.